# Transitioning from Newsstand apps to non-Newsstand apps

Tags: ios, ios9, newsstand-kit

In iOS9 there won't be a Newsstand app anymore. What will happen with apps that are using Newsstand? Is there some solution, or will developers just have to re-implement apps to no-Newsstand and count on users to update their apps before they update to the new iOS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, That's true.
According to iOS 9 updates [here.](https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/)

> **Updates in iOS 9**
>
> Changes are coming to Newsstand this fall with iOS 9. While publishers can still distribute periodicals on the App Store with auto-renewing subscriptions, the Newsstand app will no longer be pre-installed.
>
> **What to Expect**
>
> Individual Newsstand apps will now install directly to the Home screen. If a customer had Newsstand apps installed prior to updating to iOS 9, Newsstand will become a folder titled “Newsstand” and their existing apps will be placed in this folder.
>
> Newsstand app icons will no longer be the cover of the latest issue. You should review and update your App icons.
>
> You will still be able to update your issue preview screenshots and metadata without submitting a new binary.
>
> Background downloads will continue and existing subscriptions will be unaffected.

You can also refer to [News App - Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_Publishing_Guide/NewsTour.html) for more information